# Why do we use Constants?

Tags: java, android

Why do we use constants and initialize them in the code?I don't get why do we use them. For example here:

```
  public class utils {

     public static final String BASE_URL = 
    "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";

    public static final String ICON_URL = 
    "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="; }
```

Comment: As opposed to what? Just inlining that string in the code? Because now that string has a name and some *semantic meaning*.

Comment: So you have a single source of truth throughout your code. Suppose you switch to the next API level. In the code above, you have to change it in just two places (and it should be just one). If you instead used the literal string everywhere you called the API, you'd have to fix all those times. (And you during development you didn't mistype it.)

Comment: it will be easy to maintain. and it increases the readability.

Comment: You can keep all constant values in the same place. One change in this class can will be reflected to the whole app. Suppose you want to change your base url. If you inline the url, you may have to go around and change everywhere. But with a constant, its a one line change in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constant basically use for maintain and manage your constant value in one place. for example, if you going to hit server url multiple time can we avoid multiple time declare same url. Sometimes we need to set delay for Runnable on that time we can create Constant value (i.e public static final Integer DELAY = 5000; ). use for all runnable. See Below Example.

```
private static final Integer DELAY_TIME = 3000;
private Handler mHanlder = new Handler();

mHanlder.postDelayed(mAnimRunnable, DELAY_TIME)// Same Delay using one Constant variable.
mHanlder.postDelayed(mTextUpdateRunnable, DELAY_TIME)// Same Delay using one Constant variable.

private Runnable mAnimRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
         //Your Animation Task  
        }
    };

    private Runnable mTextUpdateRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
         //Your Text update Task  
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I got it

Answer (score 1):

It is helpful to have constants so if you want to make a change later on, you don't need to look for the line in your code where you put an URL or something.
You change it in one place, and all other references to this constant are up to date.

I hope I answered your question.

Regards,